# ionic Different hardware back button callback for different controllers

Tags: ionic-framework

i need to do different things on hardware back button click in different controllers. i used the following code in each controller:

```
$ionicPlatform.onHardwareBackButton(function() {
   alert("click on hardware back button");
}
```

the problem is when using registerBackButtonAction in one controller, it seems to override the same action in all controllers.
i know i can put this code is app.run() and check for state name, but i need to access some controller specific properties(and functions) when clicking back button, so putting in app.run will not work for me.

can anyone help me with this?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can mention your state of the inside the registerBackButton

look here

```
$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function(e) {
    //do your stuff
    if($state.current.name=="login") {
        console.log(e);
     e.preventDefault();
     alert('login');
     //navigator.app.exitApp();
    }
    else{

      $ionicHistory.goBack();
    }

    }, 101);
```

You can use the above code inside the controller and mention the state where it should work so that you can do your stuff in else part i reefer you to go on this one.

For more details you can take a look at this [tutorial](http://www.gajotres.net/ionic-framework-handling-android-back-button-like-a-pro/)

Comment: hi @MohanGopi and thanks for your answer. but if you look at the question i mentioned i know that i can do something like what you suggested. but the problem is i need to access each controller's dedicated $scope in registerBackButtonAction. if i place it in one controller i can only access to it's $scope and can't access to $scope of other routes. tnx

Comment: use $rootscope for that